# Finding pattern in log file

Tags: shell, grep

How can I pick all the ERROR and WARN and FATAL line from a log file with today's date? Thanks in advance.

My log file are like below.

```
[2017-04-24 17:26:48,385] WARN ******* GOODBYE /10.170.208.1:35084 ******** (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler)
[2017-04-24 17:26:48,385] WARN Ignoring unexpected exception (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler)
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1220)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.put(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:339)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler.shutdown(LearnerHandler.java:654)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler.run(LearnerHandler.java:647)
[2017-04-24 17:26:48,385] INFO Reading snapshot /bnsf/kafka/zookeeper/version-2/snapshot.900000000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileSnap)
[2017-04-24 17:26:48,476] INFO Notification: 1 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x243970000003b (n.zxid), 0x243aa (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 1 (n.sid), 0x243a5 (n.peerEpoch) LOOKING (my state) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2017-04-24 17:26:48,496] INFO Notification: 1 (message format version), 2 (n.leader), 0x243970000003b (n.zxid), 0x243aa (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 2 (n.sid), 0x243a5 (n.peerEpoch) LOOKING (my state) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[
```

Comment: use grep. See man grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -E "^\[$(date +%Y-%m-%d).*(FATAL|ERROR|WARN)" logfile
```

For your example, we get this output:

```
[2017-04-24 17:26:48,385] WARN ******* GOODBYE /10.170.208.1:35084 ******** (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler)
[2017-04-24 17:26:48,385] WARN Ignoring unexpected exception (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler)
```

Use `-A n` option if you need to include a few lines after the match to cover multi-line logs.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would probably be to use grep.  You could use `date +%F` to get the current date, using it as part of the regex.  For example:

```
grep "$(date +%F).*\(WARN\|ERROR\|FATAL\)" log_file.log
```

This should grab all of the lines from the current day in log_file.log containing either 'WARN', 'ERROR', or 'FATAL'.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to have "today's date" in the format your file has.

```
$ date +%Y-%m-%d
2017-04-24
```

You can assign that to variable:

```
$ today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

Then I would use awk because ERROR, WARN, and FATAL appear in the 3rd field:

```
$ awk -v today="[$today" '$1 == today && $3 ~ /ERROR|WARN|FATAL/ {print}'
```